# Python Logarithmic Colormap/palette

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, plotly, seaborn

I want to use a colormap where the color difference for high values is high and for the rest of my values not differing a lot. I think a logarithmic colormap would be the best way to do it. I want to plot a heatmap, not matter if in matplotlib, seaborn, plotly.

The examples for creating a logarithmic colormap like here are  always creating a meshgrid, and getting something for X and Y, but I just have a 2d array(which represents an image).  : https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolor_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-pcolor-demo-py:

```
N = 100
X, Y = np.mgrid[-3:3:complex(0, N), -2:2:complex(0, N)]

# A low hump with a spike coming out.
# Needs to have z/colour axis on a log scale so we see both hump and spike.
# linear scale only shows the spike.
Z1 = np.exp(-(X)**2 - (Y)**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X * 10)**2 - (Y * 10)**2)
Z = Z1 + 50 * Z2

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

c = ax0.pcolor(X, Y, Z,
               norm=LogNorm(vmin=Z.min(), vmax=Z.max()), cmap='PuBu_r')
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax0)

c = ax1.pcolor(X, Y, Z, cmap='PuBu_r')
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

Also like in this post : [Second example for logaithmic colormap](http://googlesearchinsurance.com/?/?questions/36898008/seaborn-heatmap-with-logarithmic-scale-colorbar/36927546)

**So what would be the way to do it if I just have an image/2d array like `a=np.array([[0,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])` for example?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
plt.imshow(a, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=a.min(), vmax=a.max()))
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

If you have values that are not strictly positive, you need to mask them first, here replacing them by nan:

```
a = np.array([[-1,0,1],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = np.where(a>0,a,np.nan)

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap("viridis")
cmap.set_bad("magenta")

plt.imshow(b, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=np.nanmin(b), vmax=np.nanmax(b)), cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, but I think it is not working if the array/image contrains zeros because I get the error exception ValueError: values must all be positive.

Comment: @Varlor: well, yeah. A logarithmic scale can only take values >0, so `vmin=a.min()` will cause problems if `a` contains zeroes. One option might be to take the minimum over nonnegative values of the array (but if you have values very close to zeros, this may distort your scale). Also, consider accepting DA's answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: yes, obviously, you can only use a logarithmic scale if you have strictly positive values. I proposed a solution to dealing with values <= 0 in your array